Altium ver-24. Can not move/drag a footprint close to the board
Altium version 24: I have a completed schematic and imported PCB and I am doing components placement. Everything looked good until a heatsink was added. I added a heatsink symbol(HS1) to the schematic with 4 pins connected to GND which will be mounting holes, I created a footprint for the symbol with 4 PTH pads so that the heatsink can be mounted to the PCB. After doing ECO without error, the heatsink footprint was added to the PCB with a far distance (which is weird), the big problem is that the footprint can not be moved or dragged close to the board. Compared to all other unplaced components (near to the board), the HS1 footprint is very far away from the board.
I have created a new rule in placement rules as below, but it does not help.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

When I clicked the footprint and tried to move it, I noticed a warning message.    "DRC violation:  0 checking: Height Constraint (min = 0mil)".....don't know what that means.

This is a question about a software issue and not about electrical engineering. The better place to ask is the dedicated Altium forum.

Try following options :

Check heatsink rules (If you defined):
This suggests reviewing the rules you've set for the heatsink in your PCB design software. This could include parameters like thermal vias, clearance rules around the heatsink area, or thermal relief settings for thermal pads. Ensure these rules are correctly defined and appropriate for your design requirements.
Check PCB file DRC rules, make zero constraint:

DRC (Design Rule Check) rules are crucial for ensuring your PCB design meets manufacturing standards and electrical performance. "Make zero constraint" likely refers to verifying that there are no unintentional constraints or errors in the DRC settings that could affect the heatsink or its connections.
If heatsink having any pad (mistakenly) then assign same net to Heatsink:
This option suggests checking for any unintended connections or pads on the heatsink. If there are pads on the heatsink that shouldn't be there (possibly affecting thermal management or electrical connections), ensure they are properly assigned to the correct net or removed if unnecessary.
